# How to resolve a different type for a remote property in Apollo?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Say I have the following query:

```js
foo {
  id
  bar
  baz @client
}
```

I can (in fact, I must) create a resolver to generate the local `baz` property. So I control its data type.

Now, what if I wanted to alter the data type of `bar`, a remote property?

I want to make `bar` a BigNumber instead of a string. Imagine something like this:

```js
resolvers: {
  bar: {
    return new BigNumber(bar);
  },
  baz: { ... }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; In most situations, you can't, so add a bit of redundancy by creating a local property with the correct data type.

---

#### Basic Query

Doesn't work

```
query Foo {
  id
  bar
  baz {
    id
  }
}
```

If you add a resolver like this:

```js
export default {
  Foo: {
    bar: ({ bar }) => new BigNumber(bar),
  }
}
```

It will NOT work.

#### Basic Query with @client

Works

```
query Foo {
  id
  bar
  baz {
    id
  }
  qux @client
}
```

Just by adding another property, say `qux`, that has the `@client` directive, you will fire the `bar` resolver defined above.

#### Complex Query with Fragments

Doesn't work

If you rewrite the query like this:

```
fragment Baz on Foo {
  id
}

query Foo {
  id
  bar
  qux @client
  ...Baz
}
```

It will NOT work anymore, even with the @client directive.

---

My environment:

- apollo-cache-inmemory@^1.6.3
- apollo-client@^2.6.4
- apollo-link-http@^1.5.16
- graphql@^14.5.8
- graphql-tag@^2.10.1

And I was connecting to a blockchain subgraph hosted on [thegraph.com](https://thegraph.com). YMMV.